# How to gray out a HTML element

Tags: html, css

I would like to gray out a HTML table to make it appear that it does not apply instead of hidding it. Any ideas on how this can be done? Hopefully with CSS!

Comment: If all you want to do is make it look gray then just give it background and border colors of shades of gray.

Comment: Are you talking about a form/input?  Or just general content/text?

Comment: It is just general text and layout.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Lower the [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity).

```
<table class="grayout">
    ...
</table>
```

```
.grayout {
    opacity: 0.6; /* Real browsers */
    filter: alpha(opacity = 60); /* MSIE */
}
```

Comment: could you make it readonly as well (nothing in the table is clickable?)

Comment: For nothing in the table to be clickable, use JavaScript ```... <table onclick="return false;" ...```

Answer (score 13):

if you only want to gray out all HTML then you can use filters

```
.grayscale { 
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: gray;
  }
```

if you want user should not click on it, then place empty DIV with absolute position and 100% height / width.

here is working code
https://jsfiddle.net/rb4f7wf6/